# Cordova StatusBar plugin fails randomly

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to run an iOS Cordova app using the StatusBar plugin (version 2.3.0).

My problem is that the plugin will be loaded randomly and also works just randomly.
Sometimes I get this error on Xcode:

```
[CDVTimer][statusbar] 5.837023ms
ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["StatusBar1191468497","StatusBar","_ready",[]]
```

and sometimes it's just working fine.

My config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.3.0" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#445E75" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

I also tried removing the platform and adding it again, removing the ios.json... I always get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to call the JavaScript methods of StatusBar.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
    Statusbar.backgroundColorByHexString("#445E75");
    Statusbar.styleLightContent();
}, false);
```